# Could not covert Document to String for storage. null

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

Good afternoon, I would have a problem that appears when I commit an org.hibernate.Transaction object.

First I start the transaction: 
`Transaction tx = XXXX.getSessionFactory (). GetCurrentSession () .beginTransaction ();`

Then I persist several objects with this transaction. When I commit it gives the error: `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [persistence.XXXX.Children.Test]`

Which is caused by the `java.sql.SQLException error: Could not convert Document to String for storage.` **Null.**

Revised what is sent in the objects are the fields correctly as it has always been sent. This error when it occurs?

I'm using weblogic 10.3 and oracle 11g.

The table I'm trying to record has these fields:

`NUMBER(38,0)
NUMBER(38,0)
NUMBER(38,0)
DATE
NUMBER(38,0)
XMLTYPE
NUMBER(2,0)
NUMBER
DATE
NUMBER
NUMBER
VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)
VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)
VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)`

Comment: If you put more details it'll be easier. Include your class entity mapping.

Comment: Document  is  java org.w3c.dom.Document? and you are trying save it to xmltype column?

Comment: You haven't posted any information about query and how data is getting mapped to columns. It would be difficult to answer with this much information. Provide more information and stacktrace.